# JavaScript - array list -- On change not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function check_value()
    {
        switch(document.register.w.value)
        {
            case 'A':
                document.getElementById("wi").innerHTML = "<img src='images/A.jpg'>" ;
                break;
            case 'B':
                document.getElementById("wi").innerHTML = "<img    src='images/A.jpg'>" ;
                break;
        }
   }
```

```html
<select id="wtype" name="wtype[]" onMouseup="check_value(this.value)">
   <option value="A">A</option>
   <option value="B">B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You need to explain the problem  further to be helped.

Comment: I have an add item table. This drop-down value does not change to the selected values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the value to the function `check_value`also I recommend you use `onchange` instead of `onMouseup` I passed value 1 so that you can see the code working when you run the snippet

```js
function check_value(v) {
  switch (v) {
    case 'A':
      document.getElementById("wi").innerHTML = "<img src='images/A.jpg'>";
      break;
    case 'B':
      document.getElementById("wi").innerHTML = 1
      break;

  }
}
```

```html
<select id="wtype" name="wtype[]" onchange="check_value(this.value)">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
</select>

<div id="wi"></div>
```